# Disabling page reloading while using form

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use a form  with a checkbox as follow :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input { 
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Toggle Switch</h2>


<label class="switch">
    <form id= "test" method="POST" action="test">
})
<input type="checkbox"
   name='switch'
   onClick="document.forms['test'].submit();"
   >
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
</form>

</body>
```

So far I've been able to do it for submit button using the following script:

```
....
  // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
        $('#test').ajaxForm(function() { 
          alert("");  
        }); 
....
```

But this isn't working apparently for checkbox. Any idea how may I do it!

thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be done as below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {        
        $('#test').on('submit', function(e) { 
          e.preventDefault();
          alert("");  
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "onchange" event instead of "onclick" and check the value. If it is checked, submit the form. And remove the event after, otherwise the form can be submited multiple times when toggling.

But it sounds simpler to use a button and style it like a checkbox with an image.

```html
<button type="submit"><img src="/img/checkbox.png" alt="Checkbox" /></button>
```

You need no additional javascript for this and it is trivial to make the on/off state with CSS.

Also obviously use your `ajaxForm` function to avoid a page reload. Otherwise the "on" state will never be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) function, along the lines:

```
....
  // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        const form = document.getElementById('test'); 
        form.onsubmit = function (event) {
        alert("");  
       // For this example, don't actually submit the form
       event.preventDefault();
}

....
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `e.preventDefault();` in on click event

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/Hassuunna/pen/WNeKYgb)

[How preventDefault() works?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Also there are some mistakes in HTML structure

1. you opened label tag before the form so you should close it after
   the form.
2. there are additional bracket and parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#togglSwitch').change(function() {
    alert("Handler for .submit() called.");
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest("form").submit();
  });
});
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Toggle Switch</h2>
<form id="test" method="POST" action="test">
  <label class="switch">
<input type="checkbox"
   name='switch' id='togglSwitch'
   >
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
</form>
<div id="other">
  Trigger the handler
</div>
```

Note:- You need to add [event.preventDefault](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) and need to add submit event on change is the solution for your problem

Answer (score -1):

```
Call function on onclick of CheckBox
i.e.
<input type="checkbox" name='switch' onClick="myfunc();">
<script>
function myfunc()
{
Here write the code of Ajax to submit the form.
}
</script>
```

Comment: please try to be more descriptive in your explanation